# AS3 disable editable/selectable for textInput inside of a Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, custom-component, cellrenderer

I am currently trying to disable the selectable / editable / or change the textInput to dynamic to get my desired result.

I've got a custom datagrid with dropdowns and text input areas. However, if there is no data in my Model # column, I do not want to allow for any entry in the corresponding PurchasePrice cell.

```
col1 = new DataGridColumn("Model");
    col1.headerText = "Model #";
    c2.consumables_dg.addColumn(col1);
    col1.width = 60;
    col1.editable = false;
    col1.sortable = false;
    col1.cellRenderer = AlternatingRowColors_editNum_PurchasePrice;
col1 = new DataGridColumn("PurchasePrice");
    col1.headerText = "Purchase Price";
    c2.consumables_dg.addColumn(col1);
    col1.width = 60;
    col1.editable = false;
    col1.sortable = false;
    col1.cellRenderer = AlternatingRowColors_editNum_PurchasePrice;
```

I've tried various items in the AlternatingRowColors_editNum_PurchasePrice, but nothing seems to work as of yet. Please Look at what I've tried in my else statement of the if(__enbaled)

```
package{
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
    import fl.controls.TextInput;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ListData;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;

public class AlternatingRowColors_editNum_PurchasePrice extends TextInput implements ICellRenderer
{
    protected var _data:Object;
    protected var _listData:ListData;
    protected var _selected:Boolean;
    private var __enabled:Boolean = false;
    public static var _stage;
    public static var _alignment;
    private var tf:TextFormat;

    public function AlternatingRowColors_editNum_PurchasePrice()
    {
        tf = new TextFormat();
        if(__enabled){
                if(_alignment == 2){
                    tf.align = TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
                }else if(_alignment == 1){
                    tf.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
                }else{
                    tf.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
                }
            restrict = "0-9.";
            addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, textChange);

        }else{
            //this.selectable = false; // did not work
            //textField.selectable = false; // did not work
            //textField.type = dynamic; // did not work
            //textField.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC; // did not work
            //this.mouseEnabled = false; // did not work
            //this.tabEnabled = false; // did not work
            //textField.mouseEnabled = false; // did not work
            //textField.tabEnabled = false; // did not work
            //selectable = false; // did not work
            //this.selectable = false; // did not work
            //_enabled = false; // did not work
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            //   *** Corresponding Entry to enable was placed above ***
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
        }
        super();
    }

    public function textChange(Event):void{
        //trace(_data.Discount);
        _data.PurchasePrice = text;
    }

    public function get data():Object
    {
        return _data;
    }

    public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        _data = value;
        text = value.PurchasePrice;

        if(value.Model != "") __enabled = true;

        if (value.id % 2 == 0) {
            setStyle("upSkin", AlternateColor1 );
        } else {
            setStyle("upSkin", AlternateColor2 );
        }
    }

    public function get listData():ListData
    {
        return _listData;
    }

    public function set listData(value:ListData):void
    {
        _listData = value;
    }

    public function get selected():Boolean
    {
        return _selected;
    }

    public function set selected(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _selected = value;
    }

    public function setMouseState(state:String):void
    {
    }
    override protected function drawLayout():void
    {
        textField.setTextFormat(tf);
        super.drawLayout();
    }

}
}
```

Am I just approaching this the wrong way? Instead of trying to stop the mouse, tab, or convert the text field to dynamic, should I be attempting something else in order to get the desired result?

Thanks,
jc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest approach is to change the `TextField` type itself and then change it's `selectable` property:

```
//disable input
tf.selectable = false;
tf.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;

//enable input
tf.selectable = true;
tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
```

Also don't forget to set the `mouseEnabled` & `tabEnabled` properties as appropriate/needed for your fields.

Comment: If I use `TextFieldType` as you did, it gives me an error. I corrected it with this code instead of yours: `tf.type = "dynamic";` and `txtAnswer.type = "input";` Probably it will be useful to someone else ;)

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to import the TextFieldType at the top of your class / page / frame as:

```
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
```