# In ActionScript how to disable CTRL+V Paste in a TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I disabled the Paste option in right click of TextArea using:

MyField.textField.mouseEnabled = false;

But still i can paste any text using CTRL+V is there anyway to stop it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314383/as3-disable-editable-selectable-for-textinput-inside-of-a-datagrid

Comment: maybe this one could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen for TEXT_INPUT event, and prevent default if text.length is greater then 1.

```
MyField.textField.addEventListener( TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onTextInput );

function onTextInput( e:TextEvent ):void 
{
    if( e.text.length > 1 ) 
       e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You can also change the type of the TextField during run-time from input to dynamic - this will prevent all input.